# How to insert a dynamic array data into MySQL table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4

I am have managed to scrape data from a table of a specific website. But the table that appears is dynamic and keeps changing based on the drop down list option selected. Some options display a table that has 2 or 3 or 4(randomly)
I have managed to save that data into list named 'data' and later on convert it into an array.
Now the problem is that the method I have used now to insert that data into the MySQL table only inserts the first row. How do I get it to insert all the rows by doing the work dynamically???

I hope you get my point. If you don't then please ask.

```
for tr in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="GridViewRoadsStatus"]'):
    tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    data.append([td.text for td in tds])

    # for storing data into MySQL table
    myarray = np.asarray(data)
    newdata = myarray[0]
    Section_Name_To = newdata[0]
    Status_To = newdata[1]
    Reason_To = newdata[2]
    Novalue = newdata[3]
    Section_Name_From = newdata[4]
    Status_From = newdata[5]
    Reason_From = newdata[6]

    insertstmt = ("insert into sectionname (Section_Name_To,Status_To,Reason_To,Novalue,Section_Name_From,Status_From,Reason_From) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (
    Section_Name_To, Status_To, Reason_To, Novalue, Section_Name_From, Status_From, Reason_From))
    cursor.execute(insertstmt)
    cnx.commit()

    data.clear()
```

['Main Rd - Tariq Shaheed Rd' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'Tariq Shaheed Rd - Main Rd'
 'Normal' ' ' 'Tariq Shaheed - LRR Service Rd' 'Normal' ' ' ' '
 'LRR Service Rd - Tariq Shaheed' 'Normal' ' ']

The above is what is being stored in 'newdata'
Now when I try to insert it into the table only the values before Tariq Shaheed - LRR Service Rd is being inserted into the MySQL table

Comment: Your code is not correctly indented so we can't tell whether the `cnx.close()` call is within the loop or outside, so please first fix your indentation. Also if you get an error, please add the error message and the entire traceback to your post.

Comment: And for something different: your code is fully opened to sql injections (and possibly escaping problems), cf http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: There is no error message but the problem I mentioned is that the above code only inserts the first row of the table that I have scraped although I have the entire data of the table in 'data' list

Comment: until you fix your code indentation there's just no way to help you.